# Bootstrap form page is not displayed properly on small size screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm editing a bootstrap countdown page, and currently I'm stuck with this form.
While on big screens it is look good, once I get it smaller than 800 px it started to see more like that...
Any suggestions on fixing it?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                <h1>WeBuild</h1>
                <h2 class="subtitle">We're working hard to improve our website and we'll ready to launch after</h2>
                <div id="countdown"></div>
                <form class="form-inline signup" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter your email address">
                  </div>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-theme">Get notified!</button>
                </form>     

            </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/jxmoe88g/

Answer (score 4):

Per the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries), `col-xs-*` is what handles "extra small" devices (less than 768px). Also,

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller devices. Therefore, e.g. applying any `.col-md-*` class to an element will not only affect its styling on medium devices but also on large devices if a `.col-lg-*` class is not present.

In other words, you don't need all three grid classes on your `div`. If you want it to be a `-col-12` across all devices, try:

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
```

**Edit** - Fixed the fiddle posted by Preben: http://jsfiddle.net/jxmoe88g/1/

Comment: Nice fix. Good catch. I didn't fully understand what he was asking :-)

Comment: @Preben Cheers. FYI, the External Files link to Bootstrap was broken, because it had some `<link rel=""` garbage inside. I grabbed the direct URL and pasted it in.

Comment: I fixed the classes, but the main problem still exist. On normal screen the form and button are inline. Once I make screen size smaller - the input form stuck to the left side of the screen, but button stays centered. so they look like this --- __. How to make them stay inline or at least both centered,  when I'm shrinking screen size?